# Reduced copy of zabbix database

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, disk-space

I've a relatively big postgresql database that tooks a lot of space in a server. The database stores a zabbix system used to monitor data that I've to safely keep, so history tables are quite big.

My guess would be to replicate this big DB in another server with a lot of space (but not so stable network connection), and keep a somehow light version of recent data in main server.

I took a look to options as partitioning, WAL..., but I think that they don't fit the requirements, so I'm starting to consider that I've to redesign the full system.

Any ideas? all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to reduce the historic table size deleting part of that historic data and for example, preserve only last 6 months.

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM historic_table WHERE date < 'now'::timestamp - '6 month'::interval) TO '/tmp/historic_table.'||extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc')||'.csv';

DELETE FROM historic_table WHERE date < 'now'::timestamp - '6 month'::interval)
```

Then keep that backup somewhere else, or compressed in your server.

A cron job to do this periodically could help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of the "TO file" command, I didn't even knew that. The problem is that I need to have the full database in the other server with big space. I would need to have both databases in sync, but removing old history from only one of them.

Comment: Maybe a more efficient way is to partition data so important data can fit in both. Take a look at https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/zabbix2_postgresql_autopartitioning @avelo

Comment: That zabbix autopartitioning script is very interesting, even more if comes from zabbix page as I supose it copes all possible issues with history_xx and trends databases. But I think that this would not fit well with the replication problem. My guess would be to set-up a master-slave system (my best bet would be Slony-I and avoid WAL sync or autopartitioning) and then find a way of removing old data from the master without remove it on the server. This way I would have a light Master with only the newer data and a heavy Slave with all the data.